# How to install .Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile (using Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0

I tried to open an old project developed by someone else in Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition and it said this project is targeting .Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile which is not installed on the system.

From where can I install this? I tried to download from following page but it is not listed anywhere.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet_sdks.aspx

Here's list of frameworks shown in Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: You need the multi-targeting pack.  Hard to get for 4.0, it is included with the VS installer but not available as a separate download that I can find.  You need to explain what is "special" about your VS install.  Or just move on and retarget to 4.5

Comment: I have changed my project to target 4.5 but I fear it won't work on Windows XP (I am using Windows 7) for which this project is inteded to run. And I might have to install 4.5 on client machine also (running Windows XP)

Comment: Well, that's just a small part of the problems you have.  Not being able to test and debug your app are *much* more troublesome.  Only thing that makes sense is to downgrade to VS2010.  Or say NO!

Comment: Cannot reproduce this issue, as my installation works fine. Maybe you need to try another machine.